# unpivot query join to other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below

```
with t as (
     select ID, name, tag, tag_1, tag_2, tag_3, tag_4, location from table_one
     )
     select * from t
     unpivot (
     value for _tag_ in (tag,tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4)
     )
```

Now, I want to join 3 other tables table1, table2, table3 to the above, I need to select other columns example col1, col2, col3 from those tables. Any idea on how to proceed with that.

Comment: just do select * from t join the other tables - you can also just treat 't' as a subquery instead of creating a formal CTE

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lateral join in Oracle 12C+:

```
select u.*
from t cross apply
     (select id, name, tag from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_1 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_2 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_3 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_4 from dual
     ) u;
```

You can then join to `u` as you would anything else:

```
select u.*, . . . 
from t cross apply
     (select id, name, tag from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_1 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_2 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_3 from dual union all
      select id, name, tag_4 from dual
     ) u join
     x
     on u.? = x.?;
```

In Oracle 11, you can do something similar if you make the `unpivot` a subquery or CTE.